# How to set margin left and right to the center div when using float:left

Tags: css

Currently I have 3 divs with content that echoes out dynamically using php and mysql.

How can i target the center div of these 3 and apply css to it?

The purpose is to separate the first, second and third div using margin-left and right on the center div to make it look more neat and ofcourse to separate the content of each div so it doesn't look like a complete block of text.

And adding `margin:left;` to the class is not possible because i want the first div to display *"inline"* with the div above.

So is there a way to target the center div that is outputted and applying css to it?

**The php:**

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
$cont_short .= "
    <div class='cont_short'>
      <h1>".$row['title']."</h1>
      <p>".$row['description']."</p>
    </div>
    "
    ;
```

**The CSS:**

```
.cont_short{
  float: left;
  width: 31.5%;
  padding: .4em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  background: #DDD8DC;
  -moz-border-radius: .2em;
  -webkit-border-radius: .2em;
  -khtml-border-radius: .2em;
  border-radius: .2em;
}
```

Comment: PHP & MySQL should have no bearing on this. You can achieve what you need with CSS selectors.

Comment: PHP code is not useful for solving CSS problems, please provide the generated markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going with the line below

*How can i target the center div of these 3 and apply css to it?*

Than you can use `nth-of-type` selector to target the second `div` specifically...

```
div.wrap div.cont_short:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/r4XVp/)

So the above selector selects 2nd `div` which is nested inside element having a `class` of `.wrap`

Comment: Might be worth nothing that if you plan to support IE8 or older, this technique will not work.

Comment: +1 that's a good resource, but then necessitates added overhead.

Comment: @SetSailMedia something better than nothing :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien So if i add selectvizr aswell as the css you've added it will work with older versions of browsers and IE?

Comment: @JimSundqvist Yes.. or else you can also add a class using php on iteration

Comment: @Mr.Alien Hey again. Hope i can take another few minutes from your time. I can't seem to get selectvizr to work. It doesn't load the css file if using the specified versions of IE

Comment: @JimSundqvist Did you choosed the libraries listed there?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I chose a library, added it to the library script. as a full link: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>` however the code beneath it is commented, is it supposed to be?
`<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/selectivizr.js"></script>
   <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" /></noscript>
 <![endif]--> `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45748/discussion-between-jim-sundqvist-and-mr-alien)

Comment: @JimSundqvist Sorry I was off to sleep, ping me once you back

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm back, sorry for taking so long. I've got the chat open, so please send a message there if possible :)